# Universal linking with website by using swift

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I using Universal-linking in my application, For that, I make the following apple-app-site-association file, like with the following code.

I place this file into server please find here:- http://dev.2ULaundry.com/apple-app-site-association

I add Domain URL into under associated domain into Capabilities of project file also.

But my Universal linking is not working anyone please help to me.

```
"applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "D929J2.com.apple.wwdc",
                "paths": [ "/scheduled-pickups/","/new-schedule/", "dashboard-1", "/refer-a-friend/", "/price-list/", "/give-a-gift/", "/locations", "2u-rewards/", "payments/"]
            }
        ] 
     }
 }
```

And add the following code into appdelegate file also for hadling.

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                         continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
                         restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool
        {
            if userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb {
                let url = userActivity.webpageURL!
                let userurl = url.absoluteString

                    if userurl.contains("/scheduled-pickups/")
                    {
                        let innerPage = UIStoryboard.loadPickupController()
                        innerPage.selectedfrom = SelectedFromVc.Deeplinking.rawValue
                        let nav = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: innerPage)
                        nav.isNavigationBarHidden = true
                        self.window?.rootViewController = nav

                    }
}
```

Comment: you have to verify your website domain with this AASA validator https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/

Comment: Hello, it will show the error,  Actually these file place by my backend person into the server, how do we resolve that issue.

Comment: You have to get the json file or let them know about the aasa validator, please see my detailed comments below

Answer (score 1):

Before the implementation, you have to verify your website domain with this AASA validator https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/. It has few warnings so please run the validator and fix the issue.

As per you shared, the domain starts with "http" but

> Universal link only serves "https"

and also it would be good if you are placing the AASA file in the below path

https://dev.2ulaundry.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association

> Since I spent lot of times on Universal link & App links, my
>   recommendation is to use [Firebase dynamic link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links) for free or
>   [Branch.io](https://branch.io/) before wasting your time.Universal link will create lot of issues
>   like you can't check the app availability(app installed or not) and
>   you can't passing the parameter via Apple/Play store.

Comment: You have duplicated my answer :)

Comment: Cool dude, my point is to highlight the problems with the universal link. Even if he goes for Universal link those are all the basic validations. :-)

Comment: Hello RaviChandra thank you AASA file location path well-known is our own folder or must and should be name .well-known

Comment: You have to create the folder (name called .well-known) in your root directory and set the path as expected. For eg: in nginx server we are setting the path in default.config file like this "location /.well-known/apple-app-site-association {
      try_files $uri /.well-known/apple-app-site-association;
     }"

Answer (score 0):

You should check is your domain valid for using universal links. You could do it here: https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/.

I've checked your domain http://dev.2ulaundry.com there and there are some issues with your domain. Fix them and it should be fine.

Comment: I have no idea how your server has been configured but you could try to put `apple-app-site-association` file inside .well-known/ folder in the root folder of your side.

Comment: In my side means there is no file in my local Xcode project, that file into server only.

Comment: Sure, this file should be available on server side.

Comment: Is any idea on that how to place that file into server.

Comment: What do you mean? If you already placed this file on server then you should be able to create a folder `.well-known/` and place this file inside this folder for the site.